# eslint can't cope with #include preprocessor directive in javascript

Tags: javascript, atom-editor, eslint, extendscript

I'm using eslint in atom to lint my extendscript code for Adobe After Effects. Extendscript  is based on ECMAScript, so eslint is really useful and I'm learning JS code style goodness every day.

But there's one hiccup. Extendscript uses preprocessor directives so that you can use #include and a couple of other things. This causes eslint to have hissy fits and vapors. Using `//eslint-disable-next-line` or `/*eslint-disable*/` doesn't work because the `#` causes a fatal parsing error, rather than breaking rules *per se*.

Is there any workaround? Or am I going to have to use `eval()` to include my libraries?

Comment: Can you run the preprocessor only, and then call eslint upon the result?

Comment: Any chance `//@include 'path/to/file'` would work?

Comment: @torazaburo Yes, `//@include` will solve the problem, as well as `//@includepath` can replace `#includepath` and `//@ targetengine` can replace `#targetengine`. Do you want to turn this into an answer?

Comment: @torazaburo yes, thanks. Turn it into an answer and I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using eslint on ExtendScript with `#include` style pragmas can be done with the [`eslint-plugin-skip-adobe-directives`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-skip-adobe-directives) processor plugin.

Install for your package with:

```sh
$ npm install --save-dev eslint-plugin-skip-adobe-directives
```

Then add in `.eslintrc` config:

```
"plugins": [
  "skip-adobe-directives"
]
```

The other alternative these days would be to write the script as ES6 or something nicer to work in, then transpile back to 3rd Edition ECMAScript using [`extendscriptr`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/extendscriptr) perhaps.